# Custom Facebook Like Page button using jQuery trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, facebook-like

The default facebook button to like your facebook page is going to look pretty rubbish on my website so I wanted to create a custom designed button.

I have the code below trying to use jquery trigger to mimic the clicking of the facebook like button. I don't think this works though as the facebook like button is within an iFrame.

Can anyone see how this could work?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("a").live("click", function() {
        $(".connect_widget_like_button").trigger('click');
        return false;
    });
});
```

And

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=164366676978480";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/Google" data-width="292" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>

<a href="#">test button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You think right! That won't work because of the iframe. Also check out the following question for more details about changing the like button an legal matters. [Facebook, how to change like button image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920945/facebook-how-to-change-like-button-image)