# React how to show button over fullscreen video?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, fullscreen

I have a fullscreen video iframe. I want show button over it. Is it possible? Z-index doesn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [div on top of iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317626/div-on-top-of-iframe)

Comment: No, I have tried that way(

Answer (score -1):

```
A Modal allow to display a component on top of another and you can read more about it on this link (https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal).
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Alert,
  Modal,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>

            <TouchableHighlight
              style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3" }}
              onPress={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              }}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>

      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.openButton}
        onPress={() => {
          setModalVisible(true);
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Show Modal</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 22
  },
  modalView: {
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5
  },
  openButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#F194FF",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  modalText: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: 1. It's react-native
2. It's doesn't help.