# Can we modify css of facebook social plugins?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to remove the “Facebook social plugin” text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870082/how-to-remove-the-facebook-social-plugin-text)

I am new to facebook social plugins and i wanted to customize css of social plugins provided by facebook. Basically i want to change the way like logo and facepile is displayed. I want to show faces from facepile in circle rather than rectangular box.

I have read facebook developer docs but there isn't much documentation about how to customize social plugins. I also searched it on stackoverflow and other websites but the answer given there are not working as facebook has changed social plugin on NOV 7,2012.

I also read solution on [line 25 website](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-add-a-custom-facebook-like-box-to-your-site) and on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874755/fblike-box-custom-css)
but both are not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check my answer in the above question!

Comment: I have checked your answer there and i understood that we can not do that.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can (or could) make some plugins a little bit customized.
In the Like Box or Fan Box you could add a external CSS file from a parameter &css= at the iframe src call. But it seems stopped work at last days.

Anyone got that problem too? I'm searching for a anwser, but didnt find nothing.

Comment: Same here, I used the old plugin with css but since 25 Jan it looks like css is ignored, worked fine for years... :(

Comment: Same here. Worked for years, but stopped working recently. I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Thank you Guys for replies. I haven't found any solution. I decided to go with default look.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't update or override css of facebook plugins because most plugins of facebook rendered in iframe.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for your reply. I have decided to go with default look.